# java For loop simple code - output clarification

Tags: java, for-loop

Can somebody explain me how this code prints `8 2` as the result?

```
public class Check{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int x=0;
        int y=0;

        for(int z=0;z<5;z++){
            if(++x>2||++y>2){
               x++;
            }
         }

         System.out.println(x+" "+y);

    }
}
```

Comment: Dou you know what ++x does?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The receiving out put is 8 2. I want some explanation, hw it comes :)

Comment: Thankz everyone....Finally I understood it ...:)

Comment: And a very bad example of how to write code! I see questions like this asked a lot, but anyone seriously writing code for a living should not write code like this. Yes, you can figure out what it does, but it's VERY easy to misunderstand or, if you want to change it, it ends up being wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to understand unknown pieces of code:

1. Indent the code properly. That helps enormously with reading code and it's a simple, safe operation to get used to the code.
2. Try to find a different way to express the same code in a more simple way. Run the code after each change to make sure your changes didn't break anything.

   This means to replace `++x` with `x=x+1` in the right place.
3. Untangle nested/complex `if()` conditions.

So the rewritten code could look like this:

```
for(int z=0; z<5; z ++) {
    x = x + 1;
    if( x > 2 ) { // first half of the OR
        x = x + 1;
    } else {
        // first half of the OR is false, we end up here
        y = y + 1; // pre increment
        if( y > 2 ) {
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Another good solution is to use poor man's debugger:

```
for(int z=0; z<5; z++) {

    System.out.println("x="+x+", y="+y+", z="+z); // add this line in several places to see what happens
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In iteration 0, 1, the condition is not true, so it ends with `x=2, y=2`.

From iteration 2 onward, the first condition `++x>2` is true, so the second one is not evaluated again. `y` remains fixed at 2. For each following loop, `x` is increased twice (once evaluating the `++x>2`, once by the `x++;`). So `x` becomes 4, 6, and 8.

Comment: So, in a OR logical statement check, if the 1st condition is TRUE, the second one is always not evaluated ?

Comment: @AchiniSamuditha yepp thats it :)

Comment: @TheCat despite the similitude, `|` is a completely different operation from `||`. It is like comparing `||` with `+`.

Comment: @achini ya thas true.. In case of || and && only . ie if first is true its true in || and If first is false then its false in &&.. But its not in | or & ..

Answer (score 6):

`++x` is a **pre increment of x** your evaluation would be something like below.

```
INITIAL VALUES:
x=0, y=0
    z=0, 
    INVARIANT FOR z: z<5 ()
    WHEN z=0 
       CHECK IF 1>2 || 1>2
               THEN x++
     WHEN z=1
           CHECK IF 2>2 || 2>2
                THEN x++

     WHEN z=2
          CHECK IF 3>2 || 2>2 y cond is not eval as x cond satisfied
                THEN x++(inc 3++)

     WHEN z=3
          CHECK IF 5>2 || 2>2 // y cond is not eval as x cond satisfied
                THEN x++(inc 5 by 1)

     WHEN z=4
          CHECK IF 7>2 || 2>2 //y cond is not eval as x cond satisfied
                THEN x++(inc 7 by 1)


THUS : FINAL OUTPUT x= 8, y=2
```

Comment: @AaronDigulla haha, yeah my bad .. checnged it

Comment: yes.but can u explain how the final output comes as 8 2 ? as I feel, since both the conditions here (CHECK IF 1>2 || 1>2)
 is faulse it will not execute X++, Right?,

Comment: @AchiniSamuditha follow the same evaluation, you'd get the final result.. break it down further like i have explained

Comment: You are missing that, in an or `||`, the second expression will only be evaluated if the first expression is false. That is what explains that `y` remains at `2`; when `++x>2` is true `++y>2` is not checked and so `y` does not increment further than 2.

Comment: @SJuan76 it was a copy paste mistake .. just edited my code :)

Answer (score 4):

It's all about how you have the ++x/++y in the if check.  Follow the logic:

x=0 y=0 z=0

Then you hit the if line, as ++x is 1 it is not >2, so it runs the ++y part making y=1, the if results in a false and your values are now:

x=1 y=1 z=0

iteration 2 happens, with z=1
Then you hit the if line, as ++x is 2 it is not >2, so it runs the ++y part making y=2, the if results in a false and your values are now:

x=2 y=2 z=1

iteration 3 happens, with z=2
Then you hit the if line, as ++x is 3, it is >2, so the x++ executes (making x=4), the ++y does NOT execute because the OR was true in the if.  The values are now:

x=4, y=2, z=2

Repeat this till z=5 and you end up with x=8, y=2

Answer (score 1):

Intial Execution of the loop

`z=0 --> x=1, y=1`

`z=1 --> x=2, y=2`

For above, condition in if is false.

Also, observe, for every valid execution of condition in if, x increments by 2 (pre-increment and post-increment).

Why y=2 remained same..? Logical operator '||' execution, if first condition is true, it wont look or execute for the other condition

`z=2 --> x=4, y=2`

`z=3 --> x=6, y=2`

`z=4 --> x=8, y=2`

x=8 --- and y=2

Answer (score 1):

in an 'if' statement like this:

```
if (conditionA() || conditionB()) {...}
```

if conditionA() returns true, conditionB() is not called at all because there's no need, the whole if-statement must be true.

in detail:
the loop executes 5 times.

1st time: x and y incremented to 1 in the if() statement.

2nd time: x and y incremented to 2 in the if() statement.

3rd time: x incremented to 3, and that's enough to trigger execution of the inside of the 'if' block. y is not incremented again because there's no need to evaluate the expression after the || (OR) if the first part is true.

4th time: x incremented to 5, if() still true, so the x is incremented again to 6.

5th time: x incremented to 7 in the if(), and 8 in the block.

Final result: x is 8, y is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since the System.out.println() statement is outside the loop, the println statement only runs once.  Every loop iteration, the if statement checks if the values of x and y are greater than 2; however, first it increments both of their values.  The first 3 times through the loop, the conditions are not met but x and y are still incremented.  Every time after that, x and y are both incremented by one; however, since the condition is met, x is incremented an additional time.  In short, this is what x and y look like after each iteration:

```
z   x   y
--  --  --
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   4   3
3   6   4
4   8   5
```

EDIT: Due to the short-circuit logic in the if statement (||), only the first part of the expression gets evaluated and y never gets incremented.  As a result, y would just stay at 2.

Comment: but the final answer is 8 2. not 8 5 :(

Comment: Oh wait - that's because of the short-circuit logic.

Comment: tnx all. I understood the theory

Answer (score 0):

For loop execute 5 times.. When its coming to if x and y will get increment by 1 for first 2 times its same.on the time x&y are 2 but the if condition not satisfied. On 3rd time x will be 3 and it won't check y so y will not increase and it will go inside if and increment again. So y will be 2. But x will increment by 2*2=4 times so x=8 and y=2